# Excel: Formula Check

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
=DATEDIF(B1,NOW(),“Y”) & “ Years, ” & DATEDIF(B1,NOW(),“M”) & “ Months, ” & DATEDIF(B1,NOW(),“D”) & “ Days ”
```

I am trying to get the above formula to show how long an employee has been employed based off their hire date in a given cell. However, it's simply not working and giving me a "name" error. I am not sure what's causing this.

Comment: You are also going to want to change the Month and days to include the year and month respectively: `=DATEDIF(B1,NOW(),"Y") & " Years, " & DATEDIF(B1,NOW(),"YM") & " Months, " & DATEDIF(B1,NOW(),"MD") & " Days "`

Comment: What is in B1 and how is it stored (e.g., Excel date or text date)?